# multiple x series for a single plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to have 2 values stacked on each other per x in a matplotlib plot. For instance, age and year, roman and numerical, etc. Is there a way to put two series as x-values?

For instance my dataframe contains (L)etters, (N)umbers, (V)alues

```
L  N V
a  1 6
b  2 25
c  3 2
d  4 34
...
z 26 2
```

I would like to plot with both L and N (stacked above each other) on the x-axis and V on the y-axis.

Comment: checkout `twiny()`.

Comment: twiny sets a second y-axis. I am interested in having two values on the same x-axis and only one y-axis.